# How to measure the width

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

In the attached picture, RS can be determined as follows:
RS is obtained from fitting the function $$0.5(1+\operatorname{erf}((I\%-50)/RS))$$ where $I\%$ is the current pulse amplitude as percentage of threshold and $\operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{x}e^{-\lambda^2}d \lambda$.
It is about determining the spread of a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the relative spread as defined by the equation
$$0.5(1+\operatorname{erf}((I\%-50)/RS))$$
is proportional to the coefficient of variation. Your alternative formulation also leads to the coefficient of variation; a more direct approach to obtaining RS is to construct the tangent line at the point where the probability is 50%. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3960111/215011) for a comprehensive discussion.