# How can i define the width of a curve (RS)

Tags: calculus, statistics

I would like to determine the width of the curve - as suggested in this paper on page 133

[paper](http:////http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.460.859&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

I am very confused, since this doesnt look like a Gaussian Curve... what is this RS? Can someone explain it to me in simple terms?

Best Regards and many thanks

Comment: Indeed, it is not super clear how the value is obtained. But we can begin to understand something when we plot the mentioned function: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u58jtdwu77
I have included a tangent line; you can play with the value of the spread ($\alpha$ in my equations) to see how it affects the graph. So the spread essentially determines how steep the rise is, or the slope of the graph at a certain point. But the next question is: how is this value obtained? Well, the text only says: "... is obtained from fitting the function"- in other words, graph fitting is used to determine it.

Comment: I did not understand that either from the given picture. It just says "from fitting the function". So perhaps they used some regression methods ... But I cannot say for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "relative spread" appears to be obtained by fitting a Normal($\mu,\sigma^2$) distribution to the sigmoid curve, then computing the ratio of $\sigma$ to $\mu$.

[Here is another paper](https://mimm.mcmaster.ca/publications/pdfs/119497_vol11_1107_copyright%20notice.pdf) that discusses relative spread. Equation (3) in that paper is
$$p(n)=\frac12\left(1+\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{V_{\rm stim}(n)-V_{\rm thr}(n)}{\sqrt 2\sigma}\right)\right).\tag3$$
Using the identity $\operatorname{erf}(x)=2\Phi(\sqrt 2 x)-1$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative, equation (3) is the same as
$$p(n)=\Phi\left(\frac{V_{\rm stim}(n)-V_{\rm thr}(n)}{\sigma}\right).$$ So viewed as a function of $V_{\rm stim}$, this is the cumulative distribution function of a normal distribution with mean $\mu=V_{\rm thr}$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.
The authors of that paper define the dimensionless quantity
$$
\operatorname{RS}:=\frac{\sigma}{V_{\rm thr}(n)}\tag4$$ which is the same as $\sigma/\mu$. In other words, to compute this version of RS, you fit a Normal($\mu,\sigma^2$) distribution to your sigmoid, then define ${\rm RS}:=\sigma/\mu$.

[The paper that you are looking at](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.460.859&rep=rep1&type=pdf) omits the factor of $\sqrt 2$.
If that's not a typo, it seems there is disagreement about the exact definition of RS. At any rate we can say RS is proportional to $\sigma/\mu$.

FYI, here is [one of the earliest papers](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237820889_On_the_Fluctuation_of_Threshold_of_the_Nerve_Fibre) (1960) that discusses relative spread. [This paper](http://www.verveen.org/1963%20Nerve-ModelExp.pdf) (1963), by the same author, explicitly states that relative spread is the **coefficient of variation**.

---

EDIT: Regarding your comment about estimating the RS from the "linear part" of the sigmoid: Yes, this approach gets you within a factor of RS. Specifically, if you construct the **tangent line** to the sigmoid
$$
F(x):=\Phi\left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)
$$
at $x=\mu$, and extend the tangent line to intersect the $x$-axis at the point $(x_0,0)$, then the distance $\mu-x_0$ from the $x$-intercept $x_0$ to the threshold $\mu$, after dividing by $\mu$, is proportional to RS.

Here is the calculation: The equation of the tangent line to $F$ through the point $(\mu,0.5)$ is
$$
\frac{y-0.5}{x-\mu} = F'(\mu) = \frac1{\sigma{\sqrt{2\pi}}}.\tag a
$$
Set $y=0$ in (a) to find that the $x$-intercept $x_0$ satisfies
$$
\mu-x_0 = 0.5\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}
$$
and therefore the ratio
$$\frac{\mu-x_0}\mu=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\frac\sigma\mu\approx 1.2533\frac\sigma\mu\tag b$$
is about 25% higher than the coefficient of variation. To recover exactly the coefficient of variation, multiply (b) by $\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. can i also get this relative spread by putting a straight line through the "linear part" of the sigmoid function (for example at 20% and 80%) probability, intersecting it with the x-axis and dividing the difference between the intersection and the threshold (on the x-axis) by the threshold. are these formulations equivalent?

Comment: hopefully you know what i mean

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. A modification of your approach will get you the coefficient of variation -- see my edit. In your example I assume you meant I = 5?

Comment: chat: but if I want to calculate the RS of the data via the "normal distribution approach" then I have to fit the cumulative normal distribution or?

Comment: so by my possibility it is not possible to get the RS? is the approach over 20% and 80% not purposeful?

Comment: Yes, to get the RS you will need to fit a gaussian sigmoid function to your data, because the concept of RS assumes an erf relationship in your data, which is equivalent to a gaussian relationship.

Comment: Your 20%-80% method will give you a different multiple of RS, and you will still need to fit a gaussian sigmoid to your data. The multiple of RS you obtain will involve the quantiles of the standard normal distribution, so the result is not as clean as the tangent line approach. As for your dynamic range question, what is your definition of dynamic range?

Comment: what do you mean by will give you the multiple and will involve the quantiles of the standard normal distribution? the dynamic range would be : let x2 be that point so that p(x2)=80%, and x1 that so that p(x1)=20% - the dynamic range would be (x2-x1)*(5/3)

Comment: If you replace the tangent line by the line that goes through $(x_1,.2)$ and $(x_2,.8)$, the ratio that corresponds to (b) will have a different coefficient (not $\sqrt{\pi/2}$). By my calculation the coefficient will be a function of the number $z_{.2}$ which has the property that $P(Z>z_{.2})=.2$. Again, this is not cleaner than the tangent approach.

Comment: My final comment: If you are going to fit a gaussian sigmoid to your data, then you will obtain estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ during the fitting process, which means you already have RS $:=\sigma/\mu$.